# Custom module form problems

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am struggling in my attempts to programmatically display a form to display in my node-page view area. I have the following code in my "simplemodule".

```
function simplemodule_newcomer_form($form_state){
    $form   =   array();
    $form['simplemodule_newcomer']['name']  =   array(
        '#type'         =>  'textfield',
        '#title'        =>  t('name'),
        '#description'      =>  t(''),
        '#weight'       =>  -1,
    );
    $form['simplemodule_newcomer']['email'] =   array(
        '#title'        =>  t('email'),
        '#type'         =>  'textfield',
        '#description'      =>  t(''),
        '#weight'       =>  0,
    );
    $form['simplemodule_newcomer']['phone'] =   array(
        '#title'        =>  t('telephone No.'),
        '#type'         =>  'textfield',
        '#description'      =>  t(''),
        '#weight'       =>  0,
    );
    $form['submit_button'] =    array(
        '#type' =>  'submit',
        '#value'    =>  'enter',
    );
    return $form;
}

function simplemodule_newcomer_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state){
    //dealing with submitted data
}
```

This code works but only from a defined link in my administration menu.

What I want to do is get the form to display and submit on a specific node in view mode. So it creates the effect that there is a form to fill when visiting the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) and attach your form using [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6):

```
function simplemodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {

  if ($node->nid == $the_nid && $op == 'view') {
    $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
      '#value' => drupal_get_form('simplemodule_newcomer_form'), 
      '#weight' => 10,
    );
  }

}
```

You can use the `#weight` key to specify where in relation to the other content on the page your form will appear. Also you'll need to clear Drupal's caches when you implement this hook to make sure it's picked up.

Comment: Thanks for helping out a newbie :-)

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can use

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) and 

hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL)
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

http://drupal.org/node/1011692